# Limits for Area between two curves that don't intersect

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have this curves $$
y^2 = x+1, y=x+2, y=0, x=4
$$
The 2 curves don't intersect but $$ x=4 $$ close the area.
I draw the graphic but I have problems find out the limits.
I think is from -1 to 4 on x-axis but im not shure.
Thanks

Comment: The area is to be computed between which two curves? Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On desmos, I plotted the $4$ polynomials:

[image]

To find the area between the $4$ curves, note that there are two separate integrals: the first goes from $x=-2$ to $x=-1$, and is simply the integral of $x+2$. The second integral goes from $x=-1$ to $x=4$ and is the integral of $x+2-\sqrt{x+1}$.

In other words, you want to evaluate $$\int_{-2}^{-1}(x+2)dx+\int_{-1}^4x+2-\sqrt{x+1}dx$$You can take it from here.

Comment: Isn't the region under the parabola from $x\in (-1,4)$, also bounded between all the curves mentioned? I find the question to be unclear.

Comment: @ParasKhosla I agree the question is somewhat unclear, but generally, when students are given some number of curves and are asked to find the area between them, loosely, that means finding the area of the region directly bounded by the curves (aka, you can draw a path from some point on each curve to any point in the region without intersecting any other curve)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I can't post an image but the area should be between the parabola and the line x+2

Comment: @JuanCarlosCalderón That's precisely what this answer gives you...

Comment: Yes, thank you I have understood, it takes me a while to respond and I did not see your comment

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the graph constructed in wolfram https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2%3E%3Dx%2B1%2C+y%3C%3Dx%2B2%2C+-2%3Cx%3C4%2C+y%3E0 the figure has to be separated in two parts, one goes from -2 to 2 and the other part goes from 2 to 4, so the interval of integration in x is (-2,4).